# Xamarin Forms - From tabbed page to other screen and back to tabbed page

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, tabbedpage

I have a Xamarin Forms application based on the tabbed page structure. When I enter one of the tabbed pages I hide the navigation for that page, so I don't see two navigations (I hide the navigation of that page and not the navigation of the page where alle tabbedpages are in).

Each tabbed page has a button, when I click on that button I navigate to another screen. On that screen if i press the back button, I don't go back to the previous page (tabbed page) but I go back to the page that opens the page where all the tabbedpages are in.

What I want to achieve: From tabbed page to other screen and back to tabbed page.

// Step 1: open the mainpage

```
     MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

// Step2: we create a master detail page, the planningpage is default

```
 <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:PlanningPage/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

// Step3: The planning page has a button, when clicking on it we open

```
     await Navigation.PushAsync(new PlanningDetailPage());
```

// Step4: the detail page is a tabbedpage with some tabbes in it

```
    <TabbedPage.Children>

    <NavigationPage Title="Activity">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:ActivityPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="Vehicle">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:VehiclePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>


</TabbedPage.Children>
```

// Step5: We open the vehicle tab, it has a button, when clicking on the button, we navigate to the VehicleEditPage

```
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new VehicleEditPage());
```

When I'm on the vehicleeditpage, how can I navigate back to the vehiclepage? Because each tabbedpage is hiding it's own navigation, only the navigation of the detailpage (the page where all the tabbes are in) is showed and is used to go back to the master page.

Comment: Post your code with your attempt

Comment: It's not a good design to put the tabbed page in the navigation stack .You would better change the MainPage when you want to navigate to a new page .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I don't understand what you are trying to say. I have normal navigations pages. When I click on a particular button a tabbedpage is opening (with multiple tabs in it). Why is it a bad design? What do you recommend?

Comment: Post the full code,  which will be helpful to solve the issue .

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: TabbedPages should not be nested within Navigation pages